# Asus Zenfone 2 screen broken and blacked out, need to retrieve files.

Tags: lock-screens, screen, data-recovery

I own a Zenfone 2. My phone's screen has gone kaput completely. I just see lines in multiple hues but cannot see the unlock screen or anything beyond that. I need to recover files, however:

- No USB debugging turned on, at least I don't remember it being turned on.
- The screen is locked using a pattern and not a number.
- Can't see anything, can't even take calls. I just know if I get a call 
  because the phone vibrates.

What are my options? Really need a step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

As the screen is completely damaged you can never use it again, right? Forgetting for a second about the files, you have two options, keep it somewhere at home, or sell it for parts. But you can't sell it for parts because you have files on it that you can't delete. So at this point, it is a total loss, right?

So here's what you can do to get all your files *(and some of your money)* back.

1. Repair the phone (by paying X amount) *if the files are sensitive, keep in mind this procedure is relatively quick, so the tech can do it right in front of you*
2. Retrieve the files easily once the phone is working.
3. Sell the phone to get all the money back you spent on the screen plus more. (Or keep the phone to avoid buying another one.)

**So in the end, you will have all your files + extra money.**

You might be looking for a technical solution, but sometimes a practical one is far better.